# How to allow node-red to send only data [Temperature] that is more than 30 degrees and write in CSV file

Tags: node-red

I'm trying to send some specific data of temperature in Celsius that received an inputs from COMPORT3 which I connect with Raspberry Pi Pico and when the temperature is above 30, it will Line notify to me.

Here is the node I created:
[image]

And in the function I use this code:
[image]

So in my case, all data that it receive from the sensor Raspberry Pi Pico, every data has saved in CSV, but what I want is that for every temperature that is above 30, it will be save in csv, and for temperature which is less than 30, it will not save in CSV, so any idea on how should I fix the code in the function?

Comment: Please do not post images of code, post the actual code and then use the toolbar to format it. Images are hard to read, impossible to search or for people that use screen readers.

Comment: You also need to generate a new API key for `notify-api.line.me` now that you have published your AccessToken to the internet in an image that can not be edited

Comment: Without knowing exactly what the input to the function is we can't really answer this.

Answer (score 2):

Just move the `return msg` to inside the if block.

and probably replace the first line with

```
var temperature = parseInt(msg.payload)
```

Then remove the quotes from round `'30'` in the if statement.